# Bash multiple integers one variable

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm trying to figure out how to add multiple integers that are on a variable separated by whitespace.

ex.

```
num1=10 20 30
```

should output `60`

but I get an error when trying to echo the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute spaces with plus sign within arithmetic expansion.

```
$ num1='10 20 30'
$ echo $((${num1// /+}))
60
```

Comment: These are all great answers but they all have the variable as a string. is there a way to start them off without a string like num1=10 20 30 instead of num1='10 20 30'

Comment: @hewhocodes No. The closest to that is Cyrus' answer

Comment: @hewhocodes: background: `num1=10 20 30` assigns only `10` to variable `num1` and then `bash` tries to run a command with name `20` and argument `30` and with `num1=10` in its environment .

Answer (score 1):

With bash:

```
declare -i num1   # set integer attribute
num1=10+20+30
echo "$num1"
```

or

```
num1=$((10+20+30))
echo "$num1"
```

Output:

```
60
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively with a POSIX shell without string substitution:

```sh
num1='10 20 30'

# Transfer space Field Separated num1 into arguments array
IFS=' ' set -- $num1

# Join back arguments into num1 using + as Field Separator and compute
IFS='+' num1="$((10#$*))" # 10# sets base 10 to prevent handling leading 0 as octal numbers.

# Print 60
echo "$num1"
```